# Equilibrium points of the two-dimensional difference equation model

Tags: recurrence-relations, dynamical-systems

I am given the following two difference equations and asked to find the equilibrium points, I've looked on many online notes; however, I could not find anything that was similar to my problem, any suggestions on how to attempt it would be helpful
\begin{aligned}
x_t&=x_{t-1}y_{t-1} \\
y_t&=y_{t-1}(x_{t-1}-1)
\end{aligned}

Comment: This system looks like a discrete map $u_{t} = f(u_{t-1})$ with integer indices $t$, rather than like a continuous differential equation. So the question is: how are $t$ and $x_t$ defined?

Comment: An equlibrium point is $(x,y)$ such that $x=xy$ and $y=y(x-1)$. Can you continue?

Comment: @user539887 thanks for it I can continue that. Regards.